# How can you count the number of list elements which have been highlighted with jQuery ToggleClass?

Tags: jquery

I'm a real novice to jQuery but run a website which has an ordered list whereby users can click on each list item to highlight it.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
<ol>
<li class="cat">Item1</li>
<li class="cat">Item2</li>
<li class="cat">Item3</li>
</ol>

<script>
$( ".cat" ).click(function() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "highlight_stay" );
});
</script>
```

This works fine, but I'd like the user to be able to see how many items have been given the class "highlight_stay" in order to see their overall score, so an output like: "Overall: 17/30"

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property

```
var countOfElements = $(".cat.highlight_stay").length
```

```js
$(".cat").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight_stay");
  var catElements = $('.cat');
  var countCatElements = catElements.length;
  var countCatElementsWithHighlight = catElements.filter(".highlight_stay").length;
  
  //For debugging purpose
  console.clear();
  console.log('Overall: ' + countCatElementsWithHighlight + '/'  + countCatElements);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li class="cat">Item1</li>
  <li class="cat">Item2</li>
  <li class="cat">Item3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works perfectly. Much appreciated sir!

Comment: @Aak, Glad I could help :)